# remap `fn` key in MacOS Terminal.app for `tmux`

Tags: macos, tmux, terminal.app

I use macOS Sierra Terminal.app with tmux. When I want to disable `Allow mouse reporting` temporarily to copy/paste and clicking I need to press the `fn` key which is far away in my long apple keyboard. Is there a way to change this `fn` key to a closer key like `alt` or `shift`? I could not seem to find how after googling for a while. Thanks!